# Remove Object Using Conditional Filtering - Mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I need to do a conditional filtering using Mule 3. A sample payload is given below:

```
{
  "MainNode": {
    "ID": "123",
    "MainNodekey1": "1",
    "sysDetail": [
      {
        "sysDetail11": "localhost1",
        "sysDetail21": "443",
        "country": [
          {
            "k1": "country",
            "value": [
              "IN"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sysDetail21": "localhost2",
        "sysDetail22": "443",
        "country": [
          {
            "k2": "country",
            "value": [
              "RSA",
              "UK",
              "SL"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "sysDetai2": {},
    "sysDetai3": {}
  },
  "MainCode": "AAA",
  "MainTyoe": "BBB",
  "MyArray": [
    {
      "ObjId": "100",
      "Obj1": {
        "SubObj11": {},
        "SubObj12": {},
        "ObjCountry": "IN",
        "ObjId": "A100"
      },
      "Obj1Source": {}
    },
    {
      "ObjId": "200",
      "Obj2": {
        "SubObj21": {},
        "SubObj22": {},
        "ObjCountry": "IN",
        "ObjId": "B100"
      },
      "Obj2Source": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

The output that I need is to filter the main payload by applying a filter like below:
payload.MainNode.sysDetail.country..value == payload.Obj1.ObjCountry (which will be constant for all array elements)

Expected output is below:

```
{
  "MainNode": {
    "ID": "123",
    "MainNodekey1": "1",
    "sysDetail": [
      {
        "sysDetail11": "localhost1",
        "sysDetail21": "443",
        "country": [
          {
            "k1": "country",
            "value": [
              "IN"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "sysDetai2": {},
    "sysDetai3": {}
  },
  "MainCode": "AAA",
  "MainTyoe": "BBB",
  "MyArray": [
    {
      "ObjId": "100",
      "Obj1": {
        "SubObj11": {},
        "SubObj12": {},
        "ObjCountry": "IN",
        "ObjId": "A100"
      },
      "Obj1Source": {}
    },
    {
      "ObjId": "200",
      "Obj2": {
        "SubObj21": {},
        "SubObj22": {},
        "ObjCountry": "IN",
        "ObjId": "B100"
      },
      "Obj2Source": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: payload.MainNode.sysDetail and payload.MainNode.sysDetail.country..value are both a list in the example. What is the logic for the comparisions with more than one element in either?

Comment: For the case illustrated above, I am expecting only 1 value in the list. But it can have multiple values also like ["RSA", "UK",  "SL"]. Maybe we should go for "contains"??

Comment: 1 value in payload.MainNode.sysDetail.country..value? What about payload.MainNode.sysDetail? it is a list and the second element has several elements in country.value.

Comment: 1. payload.MainNode.sysDetail is an array list containing 1 item or more (in this case we have 2 items)
2. payload.MainNode.sysDetail.country..value is an array containing 1 or more items (here we have 1 item with country = "IN" and the second with multiple countries i.e.  ["RSA", "UK", "SL"]
3. We can get multiple array elements in payload.MyArray (here we have 2). The ObjCountry (which is payload.MyArray.Obj1/Obj2.ObjCountry) will remain the same.

Comment: 4. I need to get payload.MyArray.Obj1/Obj2.ObjCountry value (in this case value = "IN") and use that to remove the "unwanted" array item in  payload.MainNode.sysDetail.country..value (in this case remove the one having country list as ["RSA", "UK", "SL"] )

Hope I am clear. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: To simply the requirement, from the main payload, I need to remove payload.sysDetail array element where country does not contain ["IN"]